# Binding event listeners multiple times in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I'm trying to get the directory list, level by level, using JavaScript.
I have this `paths` array as input.

```
var _paths = [];
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/home/myself/hi.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/home/myself/hi1.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/home/myself/hi2.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/she/100.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/she/110.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/she/120.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/hard/soft/she/120.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/hard/soft/she/121.jpg");
_paths.push("meta1/meta2/test/work/she/220.jpg");
```

and I want to have a "test" as output, which will be clickable. After click "test", it should be replaced by "home" and "work". After click on "home" - "myself", on "work" - "hard" and "she".

I wrote this:
[CodepenCode](http://codepen.io/SterSwift/pen/XbNXqb?editors=001)

and it works only once, only when clicking on "test".

Comment: yep, i did it not quite right, changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply rebind the listeners after the directories have been drawn. You bind them only once, thus they work only once.

Wrap the binding function into a named function:

```
function bindListeners(){
  $('.sub').click(function() {
    word = $(this).text();
    filteredArr = findString(_paths, word);
    drawList(filteredArr, word);
  });
}
```

And call it at the end of `drawList`:

```
var drawList = function (paths, word) {
  var folders = getFolders(paths, word);
  if (folders.length > 0) {
    $('.canvas').html('');
    for (i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
      $('.canvas').append("<div class='sub'>" + folders[i] + "</div><br />");
    }
  }
  bindListeners();
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wvopoy?editors=001).

Comment: FYI this can fail if subfolders have same names as parents. Works for this list though.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is curious about building out the data structure:

```
(function iteratePaths() {
  var dirs = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < _paths.length; i++) {
    buildDirectories(dirs, _paths[i].split('/'));
  }
})();

function findDir(dir, obj) {
  for(var i = 0; i < dir.length; i++) {
    if(dir[i].name === obj.name) { 
      return dir[i];
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

function buildDirectories(dir, subs) {
  if(subs.length === 0) return;
  var obj = {name: subs.shift(), dirs: []};

  var existingDir = findDir(dir, obj);
  if(!existingDir) {
    dir.push(obj);  
  }
  buildDirectories((existingDir || obj).dirs, subs);
}
```